# Listing files that end in ".txt" from directories with the word "SALARIO" in its name without using pipes

Tags: command-line, bash, find

I used:

```
find . -type d -name "SALARIO*"
```

to find the directories with that word in the name and then:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt"
```

to find all files that end in txt in those directories.

How do I get both to work *at the same time* without using pipes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried it and it works for me, so I suggest you to use the following command.

```
find -path '*SALARIO*/*' -name '*.txt'
```

Comment: even if it visually state you intention to split `-path` `-name`, you can put everything in `-path '*/SALARIO/*.txt'`

Comment: Didn't knew it bac0n, nice

Answer (score 4):

Try this `find . -wholename "./SALARIO/*.txt"`

Answer (score 2):

List `*.txt` files directly under SALARIO/

```bsh
$ find -type d -name 'SALARIO' -exec sh -c 'ls $1/*.txt' _ '{}' \;
```

Or

```bsh
$ shopt -s globstar; ls **/SALARIO/*.txt
```